# Delete closet image with class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to remove the image src of the closet img with a class and set it to hidden. This is what i have tryed so far.

```
<img class="img-preview" src="http://www.abmuku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-logo-small.jpg" />
<span> random stuff here </span>
<button class="delete"> Delete

</button>


$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.img-preview').remove();
    console.log("ha")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQ5vr/38/

Comment: $(this).prev('.img-preview').remove();

Comment: Post so i can mark as answer

Comment: you want to remove the image src not the image right ? you could try doing it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.prev()` instead of `.closest()`

```
$(this).prev('.img-preview').remove();
```

[**.closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing
>   up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[**.prev()**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

> **Description:** Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it
>   retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

*to change the src and hide it you can use*

```
$(this).prev('.img-preview').attr('src','').hide();
```

Comment: I just updated the fiddle  that doesn't work  either if i add things before it

Comment: @HollyJohnson if you have things before it you can use prevUntil() instead of prev()  .. Sorry its prevAll() not prevUntil() http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/tQ5vr/40/

Comment: prevUntil() will change the source of all the pictures until it gets that one.

Comment: @HollyJohnson I update my comment, and I said sorry it should be prevAll() not prevUntil()  .. to use closest your structure must be like http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/tQ5vr/41/